# Can't access tomcat on remote linux server

Tags: tomcat

I have a remote linux server at 192.168.168.1 (subnet mask /24) which has tomcat installed and running. I know it's running because when I SSH to it and do "wget localhost:8080" I get:

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.1’

    [ <=>                                   ] 11,230      --.-K/s   in 0s

2018-07-05 15:37:21 (184 MB/s) - ‘index.html.1’ saved [11230]
```

My local windows machine is on the same network with an ip address of 192.168.168.2, and when I open up a browser and enter "192.168.168.1:8080" in the url bar, it tells me after a while that the connection timed out.

I can ping the linux server from my windows machine with no problems.

Is there something I need to configure with respect to tomcat/the linux server in order for me to be able to call tomcat from my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) the test at server side is telling you that `localhost` is resolving to ipv4 and ipv6 loopback addresses but probably not to 192.168.168.1:
`Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1`

2) Check what IP addresses is tomcat bind to with
`netstat -nlt` or `ss -nlt`
If you see an entry like
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN`
meaning that tomcat is bind to all available IPs, then it's a firewall problem on your host or on server.

**How to fix it**

- Check firewalls.
- Check `address` attribute at server.xml, if it says `localhost`, change it to `0.0.0.0` or `192.168.168.1`

  `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
      address="0.0.0.0"
      connectionTimeout="20000" 
      maxPostSize="2147483647" 
      redirectPort="8443" />`

To test, run `wget http://192.168.168.1.1:8080` on **server side**, then test from your browser.
[Tomcat official doc for Connector element](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)