# Cannot connect to EC2 web app from external browser

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2

Recently I stopped and started my EC2 instance which resulted in having to setup my web app from scratch (using Tomcat & Java).

Right now I have Tomcat running on the EC2 instance and I can properly access my web app by opening a browser on the EC2 server and pointing to http://localhost:8080/web_app_name

However, if I open a browser on my own PC and point to the public IP of the EC2 instance (e.g. ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com) then the browser returns the message:

> *"This site can’t be reached, ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com refused to connect."*

I have checked my security group for this EC2 instance, and it is allowing TCP ports 80, 443, 3389 and 8080 so I'm not sure why I cannot connect to the web app.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Will it be possible for you to share your inbound and outbound rules attached with the SG of the EC2 instance ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200776/cant-access-tomcat-on-remote-linux-server

Answer (score 1):

You can try one of the below:

1. Create a new security group with an inbound rule "Custom TCP" giving permission to ports: 0-65535 and CIDR of 0.0.0.0/0. Attach this security group to your EC2 instance
2. If you don't want to create new Security Group make sure your current inbound rules has just one rule giving wildcard access like the one above.

Answer (score 0):

As your application is running on 8080 port and ec2 Instance IP is looking for your application on 80 port.

So use loadblancer for redirecting port 80 to 8080 or try

**ec2-XXX-XXX-XXX-XXX.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/web_app_name**, you will able to render your web page.